# Determine changes in values and new rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume the following two pandas DataFrames:

```
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'col1': ['value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3'],
        'col2': ['value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3'],
    })
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'col1': ['value X', 'value 2', 'value 3', 'value 4'],
        'col2': ['value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3', 'value 4'],
    })


      col1     col2
0  value 1  value 1
1  value 2  value 2
2  value 3  value 3

      col1     col2
0  value X  value 1
1  value 2  value 2
2  value 3  value 3
3  value 4  value 4
```

What would be the best approach to:
a) find all differences in values between df1 and df2 (i.e. 'value 1' vs 'value X' in col1)
b) find any additions to df2

At the moment, I'm stuck with the following which doesn't do exactly what I need:

```
    df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
    df3.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    df3_grouped = df3.groupby(list(df3.columns))
    idx = [x[0] for x in df3_grouped.groups.values() if len(x) == 1]
    print(df3.reindex(idx))


      col1     col2
0  value 1  value 1
6  value 4  value 4
3  value X  value 1
```

Comment: So you want to compare based on the position/index? What would be your exact expected output? Do you want `df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', indicator=True).query('_merge != "both"')`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
df1['label'] = 'df1'
df2['label'] = 'df2'

key_cols = df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns).difference(set(['label']))

pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(
    subset=key_cols,
    keep=False,
)
```

Output:

```
      col1     col2 label
0  value 1  value 1   df1
0  value X  value 1   df2
3  value 4  value 4   df2
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `isin`:

```
df1[~df1.isin(df2).all(1)]
```

Output:

```
      col1     col2
0  value 1  value 1
```

And the other way for df2

```
df2[~df2.isin(df1).all(1)]
```

Output:

```
      col1     col2
0  value X  value 1
3  value 4  value 4
```

You can concatenate them if you would like.